# Event listener not updating variable in while loop

Tags: javascript, qbasic

I'm currently working on a project where I'm trying to run some QBasic code on a webpage.  I transpiled it to JavaScript and I wrote some helper functions to replace functions in QBasic.  Specifically, there's this function `INKEY$` that returns the last key the user pressed.  I tried implementing this by having an event listener update a global variable to keep track of the last key the user pressed, and then I created an `inkeys` function to return this variable.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', event => qb.key_pressed = event.key);

...

function inkeys() {
    return qb.key_pressed
}
```

The transpiled code then has something like this to get what they typed.

```
a$ = "";
while (a$ == "") {
    a$ = inkeys();
}
```

When I run it, my browser gets stuck in an infinite loop inside that loop and eventually crashes.  I've checked that the inkeys() function is running each time, but the `key_pressed` variable isn't updating.  I also know the event listener is working normally outside the loop, so I assume there's an issue with event listeners not firing inside a while loop or something?  I'm not all that familiar with JavaScript so I don't know really know what to do.  I'm getting the feeling that this is a bigger problem that's gonna involve me having to change the structure of my code.  Does anyone have any help with how I could fix this?

Furthermore, my tab crashing makes me think this while loop setup, while having worked in QBasic, may not be good for a website, and that concerns me since this particular program involves running a simulation until the user types a key.  If so, are there better methods of handling something like this that won't kill the user's tab?

Comment: there's no reason to implement that kind of loop in javascript, whenever you want to check the last key pressed, you just do `let lastKey = inkeys()` or even just use `qb.key_pressed` directly, since it looks like a global variable

Comment: JavaScript runs in one thread any infinite loop will always block it